# Windows driver signing

Tags: windows, driver, code-signing

My company is developing driver for our hardware. Now I need to sign my driver for 32 and 64 bit platforms.

Please tell, now I need to buy Authenticode certificate, right?

What CA to use?

DigiCert? GlobalSign? ( http://www.sslshopper.com/microsoft-authenticode-certificates.html )
Symantec? ( http://www.symantec.com/verisign/code-signing/microsoft-authenticode )

What is the difference between this CA offers?

I need to use tools from WDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a certificate which satisfies the kernel mode code signing policy (KMCS).

Here is a [MSDN list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487315.aspx) of possible certificate authorities.

**BUT**, it seems WHQL (or how it is currently called) needs a Verisign certificate to allow you participation in the WHQL program for windows logo ... things .... So I would buy a Verisign certificate if a windows logo is needed in the future.